# Is there any possible way to convert XML::Twig object to XML::XPath object?

Tags: xml, perl, xpath, twig

I'm using `XML::XPath` for a long time to parse xml, now the situation has come to modify the attribute value.

xml is available in a file, it will be very similar to this.

```
<AppName>
    <Action AllDay='1'StartRace='1'/>
    <StartPoint AM_PM='AM' Hours='09' Mins='30'/>
    <EndPoint AM_PM='PM' Hours='06' Mins='30'/>
</AppName>
```

I have written a perl script to change the Hours of StartPoint tag,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $fileName = 'Conf.xml';

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_roots => { StartPoint => \&ReplaceAtriValue },
    twig_print_outside_roots => 1, );

sub ReplaceAtriValue {

    my ($twig, $startPoint) = @_;
    if ( '09' eq $startPoint->att('Hours') )

    {
        $startPoint->set_att( Hours => '12');
    }
    $startPoint->print(); }

$twig->parsefile($fileName);
```

I have some how successfully replaced 09 as 12, now `$twig` has the xml object. If I send this object (`$twig`) to my SetWindow.pm which parse xml using `XML::XPath`, did not recognize this object. Is there any possible way to convert `XML::Twig` object to `XML::XPath` object so that `XML::XPath` will parse values in the `$twig` object.

Actually I have using `XML::XPath` for long back hence I have to send the `XML::XPath` object to all my own *.pm like SetWindow.pm, at the same time i need to change the values of the attribute of the standard xml before sending to my own PMs.

Thanks in Advance.

Any help is much appreciated!

rndpilot

Answer (score 2):

XML::Xpath parses XML, so that's what you should be sending to it, either in a file or as a string.

Now if you want to be clever, and all you want is to extract information from the twig, you could use XML::Twig::XPath instead of XML::Twig (::Twig::XPath is part of the XML::twig distribution), and the twig object and its elements will get enough DOM-ish methods for XML::XPath to be able to run queries on them. I am not sure it's worth it though.

Alternate methods I can think of:

- why don't you change the attributes directly using XML::XPath? a combination of `getAttributeNodes` and `setValue` should do it,
- replace XML::XPath by XML::LibXML. the interface is very similar (DOM + XPath) and it's a lot better module
- use XML::Twig::XPath to get full XPath support in XML::Twig